# Is every nonsingular linear transformation invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know that every nonsingular square matrix is invertible.
So every nonsingular linear transformation should also invertible.
But $T\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$ such that $T(x,y)=(x+y,x-2y,3x+y)$ is nonsingular but inverse does not exist.
So can I conclude that:
"If $T$ is invertible then it is nonsingular but if $T$ is nonsingular then it is not necessarily invertible."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of nonsingular?  Because I don't think your example $T$ fits the usual one.

Comment: That is right. Nonsingular is equivalent to being injective, but to have an inverse one would also need surjectivity.

Comment: @Amita According to the usual deifnition of "nonsingular", the transformation $T$ you describe is **not** nonsingular.

Comment: I read in my book that if kernel of a linear transformation contains only zero vector then the transformation is nonsingular.In the example kernel contains only zero vector so it is nonsingular.

Comment: @AmitaSingh in that case it is true only in finite dimension when the start and end spaces have the same dimension. Your sentence between quotation marks is true.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your conclusion is correct. Every invertible linear map is nonsingular, that is, it kernel is trivial. This is because non-singularity is equivalent to injectivity for linear maps.

However to be invertible a linear map must also be surjective, so non-singularity alone is not enough to conclude that a linear map is invertible. Your example of the function $T$ make this clear.

Answer (score 3):

A quick search reveals contradicting conventions.  Here are some well-established terms for properties of a linear transformation $T \colon V \to W$.

- $T$ is *injective* or *one-to-one* if for all $v \in V$, $T(v) = 0 \implies v=0$.
- $T$ is *surjective* or *onto $W$* if for all $w \in W$ there exists $v \in V$ such that $T(v) = w$.
- $T$ is *bijective* if $T$ is simultaneously one-to-one and onto $W$.

I found some sources that define *nonsingular* for linear transformations as equivalent to *injective*.  However, I am more familiar with the term applied to matrices, and equivalent to “square and invertible”.  So closer to *bijective* for linear transformations.

I agree with you that the linear transformation you describe is injective but not surjective.